# Send a different image from my web host if it was already requested by an IP address?

Tags: redirects, ip-address, image-hosting, request

I am hosting an image with my hosting provider host gator and people can request it with [www.example.com/image.png](http://www.example.com/image.png)

When an IP address requests the image [www.example.com/image.png](http://www.example.com/image.png) the first time it sends them one image.

If that IP address ever requests that same image again, I want to make it send a different image.

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: Does your site support PHP,  Is the server running Apache and if so will it allow rewrite riles in .htaccess and can you use a differrent file extension?

Comment: Also, you specifically stated an IP request. Can you use a cookie/session instea (IPs are not unique if NAT or CGN is used so the distinction is not trivial)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @davidgo yes, the site supports PHP. Host gator also supports Apache handlers but I have not used it yet but I will look into it. What file extension should I use? As long as it's am image, it's fine. The client that will request my images does not have cookies and It's ok when IP addresses of the device with client changes.

Comment: Absent cookies this becomes a programming task using some kind of database. I might tackle it by creating a php script that outputs an image (setting the mime type so the application knows to treat the file as an image). You would need to store the IP addresses in a database as they are seen and then do a lookup to see if the IP has been seen before l, dumping out the appropriate image depending on result.  You may also need to clean up the database periodically. By the time you have finished you may be better off programming something that manipulates the html rather then the image.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the suggestions, I can manage most of that. The main thing I'm not sure about is how to handle the image request. If the client requests the image with www.example.com/image.png, how can my server see that the IP address is requesting that image, run the code to determine what image to send, and then send that image. What can handle image requests like that?

Comment: As you say you can manage the PHP I've drafted an answer to address this.  I've not tested it, so it may require some tweeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request image.php (not image.png) and ensure the returned result includes the header Content-Type:image/png so it is processed as an image.

You can set the header in php with

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```

The IP address can be picked up using the apache/environment variable REMOTE_ADDR - in PHP you can get this with  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]

You can read the content of the appropriate image using file_get_contents - so you might have code like the following pseudocode php code (the bits in the asterisks need to be replaced and depend on your database and how you interact with it:

```
<?php 

# We want the browser to render this as a PNG image
header("Content-Type: image/png");

# We don't want to cache the output.
header("cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache");
header("expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:01:01 GMT");

if *$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] not in database*
      echo file_get_contents("/path/to/initial.png");
else
      echo file_get_contents("/path/to/repeatfile.png");

*insert $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] into database*

?>
```

You would call this with something html code like

```
<img src="imagemod.php" alt="changing image">
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also able to update the apache handler so I could use the .png extension to run PHP files

Comment: I also had to use "readfile" instead of "echo file_get_contents" so it could properly send the file. Thank you so much for the help!!!!!